# ipset command's output not storing to variable

Tags: bash, ipset

I am building a script to detect if IPSET exists.

```
#!/bin/bash
str=$(/usr/sbin/ipset test IPsetName 1.1.1.1)

echo "$str" #outputs blank line

if [[ $str = *"The set with the given name does not exist"* ]]; then
  echo "IPsetName not found"
fi
```

When I run this script I get this output:

`ipset v6.29: The set with the given name does not exist`

then a blank line for `echo "$str"` and I don't see the expected output from the if statement.

How to store the ipset command output to the variable?

Comment: The error message is being generated on stderr, not stdout.  So you need to do `str=$(.... 2>&1)` to capture that as well.

Comment: @StephenHarris you are correct. Thank you. This worked `str=$((/usr/sbin/ipset test IPsetName 1.1.1.1) 2>&1)`

Comment: You don't need two lots of `(..)`.  Just `str=$(/usr/sbin/ipset ... 2>&1)` would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @StephenHarris

ipset command's output is generated on stderr (not stdout) and `2>&1` captures the output to the variable.

```
str=$(/usr/sbin/ipset test IPsetName 1.1.1.1 2>&1)

if [[ $str = *"The set with the given name does not exist"* ]]; then
   echo "IPsetName not found"
fi
```

Now this if statement works as expected!